# Try every weighted combination of letters from the text result of tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-imaging-library

I've been testing text recognition from images using `pyocr` (`tesseract-ocr` and `libetesseract`). I've been applying various `PIL.ImageFilter`s and getting the result of one specific string in the image. It has not been accurate, but I have 14 different results. Between all of them, all of the correct letters of the string in the image are there. So I have enumerated each string and created a `dict` containing the characters' position as keys that contain a `dict` of each character that has appeared in that position at keys and the number of occurrences as the value. Here's a shortened example

#### String In Image:

```
2HG2
```

#### Results:

```
#Note: this is not the actual order in which the strings are produced
2HC2
2HC2
2HCZ
2HOZ
2HOZ
2HOZ
2HOZ
2HGZ
2HGZ
2HGZ
ZHGZ
ZHGZ
ZH6Z
ZN6z
```

Dictionary:

```
{
    0: {
        u'2': 10, 
        u'Z': 4
    }, 1: {
        u'H': 13, 
        u'N': 1
    }, 2: {
        u'C': 3, 
        u'O': 4, 
        u'G': 5, 
        u'6': 2
    }, 3: {
        u'2': 2, 
        u'Z': 11, 
        u'z': 1
    }
}
```

I'd like to try each combination of letters in each position until I get `2HG2`. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The goal I'm trying to achieve is to scan a car registration, get text from it, and then populate a form with the data. As a proof of concept, I'm trying to get the VIN number from my person registration. At the moment, I'm (most likely naively) applying a series of `PIL.ImageFilter`s and getting text from each. Below is my script.

```
import re
from itertools import permutations

from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import pyocr
from pyocr import builders

vins = []
characters = {}


def validate(vincode):
    """
    Validation code from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number
    """
    maps = "0123456789X"
    weights = [
        8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
    ]
    table = {
        "0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9,
        "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6, "G": 7, "H": 8,
        "J": 1, "K": 2, "L": 3, "M": 4, "N": 5, "P": 7, "R": 9,
        "S": 2, "T": 3, "U": 4, "V": 5, "W": 6, "X": 7, "Y": 8, "Z": 9,
    }

    if not isinstance(vincode, str) and not isinstance(vincode, unicode):
        return False

    if len(vincode) != 17:
        return False

    vincode = vincode.upper()
    if "I" in vincode or "O" in vincode or "Q" in vincode:
        return False

    total = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(vincode):
        try:
            products = table[value] * weights[index]
        except KeyError:
            break
        total += products

    index = total % 11

    return maps[index] == vincode[8]


def get_text(tools_, img_):
    for tool in tools_:
        if tool.get_name() == 'Cuneiform (sh)':
            continue
        # print '=======================\nUsing {}\n======================='.format(tool.get_name())
        boxes = tool.image_to_string(img_, lang='eng', builder=builders.WordBoxBuilder())
        global vins
        pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')
        vins += [pattern.sub('', x.content) for x in boxes if len(pattern.sub('', x.content)) == 17]
        # boxes = [x for x in boxes if len(x.content.strip()) != 0]
        # print boxes[3].content
        # for box in boxes:
        #     print box.content


def apply_filters_and_get_text(img_, filter_):
    for x in range(1, 5):
        print 'Applying {} size: {}'.format(str(filter_), x)
        try:
            img_ = img_.filter(filter_(x))
        except ValueError:
            print 'error on {} size: {}'.format(str(filter_), x)
            continue
        img_.save('tmp{}-{}.jpg'.format(str(filter_), x))
        get_text(tools, img_)


def count_occurrences(value):
    global characters
    for index, c in enumerate(value):
        if index in characters and c in characters[index]:
            characters[index][c] += 1
            continue
        if index in characters and isinstance(characters[index], dict):
            characters[index][c] = 1
            continue
        characters[index] = {c: 1}


tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()

img = Image.open('images/test18.jpg')
# get_text(tools)
# img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(5))
# img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
# img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE)
# get_text(tools)
# get_text(tools)
img = img.convert('L')
# get_text(tools)
# img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(5))
# img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
# img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE)
# get_text(tools)
# get_text(tools)
img = img.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 128 else 255, '1')
apply_filters_and_get_text(img, ImageFilter.MedianFilter)
apply_filters_and_get_text(img, ImageFilter.MinFilter)
apply_filters_and_get_text(img, ImageFilter.MaxFilter)
apply_filters_and_get_text(img, ImageFilter.ModeFilter)

for vin in vins:
    count_occurrences(vin)
    # print vin
    # print validate(vin)

print characters
```

Comment: Can you upload any sample image to look at it?

Comment: It's scanning a car registration to pull data off of it. I'm trying to get the VIN number as a proof of concept. But anyway, it's my personal registration, so I'd rather not lol. I'll update my question with details on the image and the script that I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a recursive function that tries every combination of the letters with priority to characters with higher weight.

```
def determine_character(characters_, tried=[]):
    next_character = ""
    current_rank = 0
    for ch in characters_:
        if characters_[ch] > current_rank and ch not in tried:
            next_character = ch
    return next_character


def determine_weight(word):
    global characters
    weight = 0
    for index, ch in enumerate(word):
        weight += characters[index][ch]
    return weight


def descramble(word="", index=0):
    global characters
    count = len(characters)
    if index == count and validate(word):
        global vin_count, valid_vins
        vin_count += 1
        valid_vins.append({'vin': word, 'weight': determine_weight(word)})
        return {'word': word, 'done': True}
    if index == count:
        return False
    tried = []
    while len(tried) < len(characters[index]):
        ch = determine_character(characters[index], tried)
        tried.append(ch)
        next_index = index + 1
        descramble("{word}{ch}".format(word=word, ch=ch), next_index)
```